# Sticky navbar react.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i found a video on YouTube for how to make a navbar, but cant figure out how to get it to stay at the top of the screen, can anyone help

function Navbar():

```js
    const navRef = useRef();

    const showNavbar = () => {
        navRef.current.classList.toggle("responsive_nav");
    };

    return (
        <header className="nav">
            <h3>.HamishMcd()</h3>
            <nav ref={navRef}>
                <a href="/">.Home()</a>
                <a href="/work">.MyWork()</a>
                <a href="/about">.AboutMe()</a>
                <button
                    className="nav-btn nav-close-btn"
                    onClick={showNavbar}>
                    <FaTimes />
                </button>
            </nav>
            <button className="nav-btn" onClick={showNavbar}>
                <FaBars />
            </button>
        </header>
```

function App():

```js
    return (
        <Router>
            <Navbar/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" exact element={<Home/>} />
                <Route path="/work" element={<MyWork/>} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<AboutMe/>} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show CSS styles/classes that you use, and CSS styles are the most crucial to make the navbar stay on top.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .nav{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    }
```

do this css it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to useful help, please add your css codes, however if you want  the Navbar to be top, you can use :

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  }
```